# How to make a queue to processing messages after 24hrs in ActiveMQ

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am working with ActiveMQ 5.8.0, I have a queue and it receives messages time to time and are immediately processed by the listener of that particular queue,Here i want the queue to process the message after 24hrs not immediately,Is there any parameter in Active MQ  where we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having consumer consume the messsages with delay of 24 hrs, I would prefer putting the messages on queue with the delay of 24hrs.

We can do it using

```
long time = 24 hours in milliseconds;
message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, time);
producer.send(message)
```

after using this configuration, ActiveMQ will schedule the message to be delivered by delay of 24 hours.

PS: You will just need to check a small thing , what happens when broker goes down before the message is delivered and does it get sent successfully if broker is up and running again

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, vihar I cant do this,Actually am looking to process messages from DLQ were i receive messages which are not successfully process by its main queue.so basically am trying to redelivery to its main queue after 24hrs or directly process the same message after 24hrs from DLQ.

Comment: Mention these exceptional scenarios when you are posting questions